# When does $V(f)\supseteq V(g)$ imply that $g$ divides $f$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Over algebraically closed fields, if $g$ is an irreducible polynomial (in $n$ variables) and $f$ is such that it vanishes on zero-set of $g$ (i.e., $V(f)\supseteq V(g)$), then $g$ divides $f$. This follows easily from Nullstellensatz, since
\begin{align}
V(f)&\supseteq V(g)\\
f\in IV(f)&\subseteq IV(g)=\sqrt{(g)}=(g),
\end{align}
hence $g|f$.

My question is whether this also holds for fields which are not algebraically closed, given that $V(g)\neq\emptyset$ (this is in general clearly needed, as $V(f)\supseteq\emptyset$ for any $f$). The question is actually equivalent to asking whether
$$g\text{ irreducible},\  V(g)\neq\emptyset \ \ \overset{?}{\Longrightarrow}\  IV(g)=(g).$$

Does this hold over any field? If not, does it at least hold over $\mathbb{R}$? Are there any counterexamples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general (= not over algebraically closed fields) it is false.

Consider for example the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and the classic counterexample polynomial $g = X^2+1$. This polynomial is irreducible, and $V(g) = \emptyset$.

Now, take any polynomial $f \notin (g)$. Then we have $g \not| f$ but trivially $V(g) \subseteq V(f)$.

---

**DISCLAIMER**: the following works if we consider polynomials in one variable.

In arbitrary fields, the answer is positive if we add the assumption that $V(g) \neq \emptyset$.

Indeed, because $g$ is also irreducible, this assumption implies that $g$ must be of degree $1$ (an irreducible polynomial with a zero has degree one). Thus, write

$$g= aX-b = a(X-b/a)$$

This polynomial has zero $b/a$, and thus in fact $V(g) = \{b/a\}$. The condition $V(g) \subseteq V(f)$ implies that $b/a \in V(f)$, thus $b/a$ is a zero of $f$ as well, and thus $f$ contains a linear factor $u(X-b/a)$ where $u$ is a unit.

It follows that indeed $g | f$ in an arbitrary field, whenever $\emptyset \neq V(g) \subseteq V(f)$ and $g$ is irreducible.

---

In more than $1$ variable over **finite fields**, the claim is **false**.

Let's work in the simplest field you can imagine: $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{F}_2$

Consider the irreducible polynomial $g =X-Y$. Then $V(g) = \{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Next, consider the polynomial $f=XY(X-1)(Y-1)$. Clearly $V(f) = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\} = \mathbb{F}_2^2$ and thus $\emptyset \neq V(g) \subseteq V(f)$ with $g \not | f$

---

Here is a counterexample for $\mathbb{R}$:

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ and $g = X^2 + (Y-1)^2$. Then $g$ is irreducible and $V(g) = \{(0,1)\}$. Put $f := X(Y-1)$. Then $V(g) \subseteq V(f)$ and $g \not| f$.

Comment: I have already noted the first part of your answer in my question. The one variable case is a nice observation, but I am, of course, interested in the multivariate case, and I don't see a straightforward way to generalize it. I have edited the question so that it is clear.

Comment: @OnDragi I added a counterexample for the case that there are multiple variables involved.

Comment: Thanks. We can also take $f=x^2-y$, which has the same zeros as $g$, and $g\not{|}f$. This can then be generalized to any $\mathbb{F}_p$ ($p$ prime), since, by Fermat's Litle Theorem, $x^p$ yields the same function as $x$, so we can take $g=x-y$, $f=x^p-y$. It seems to me that it generalizes even to any finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of characteristic $p$. So the next natural question would be whether the claim would hold for infinite fields where any two different polynomials yield two different functions $\mathbb{F}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Nice observations!  I keep looking for a proof/counterexample on the real numbers.

Comment: @OnDragi I also have the following result. If $g \in k[X,Y]$ is irreducible ($k$ infinite field) and $V(g)$ is an infinite set, then $I(V(g)) = (g)$ so then again there is a positive answer. Maybe we can start looking for counterexamples in two variables with an irreducible polynomial that has finitely many zeros.

Comment: Ah, nice, I would be interested in (idea of) the proof of that claim. Is it some simple argument? Is it essential that you have just two variables?

Comment: @OnDragi If I recall correctly, it is in Fulton's algebraic geometry. Also, I found a counterexample over $\mathbb{R}$. See my answer.

Comment: Ah, nice! That's actually super simple. It is perhaps even clearer to take $g=X^2+Y^2$ with $V(g)={(0,0)}$, and $f=X$, for which clearly $V(g)\subseteq V(f)$, but $g$ does not divide $f$ (clear even just by comparing degrees).

Comment: Yes, much clearer. I just post the first thing that I come up with haha.

Comment: Fair enough, haha. Thank you for the cooperation! And I'll check Fulton for the claim for two variables and infinite $V(g)$ (it would be actually enough for my original motivation for the question), and refer to it here if I find it.

Comment: No problem! I enjoyed thinking about the question. I looked it up quickly and it's on p9, third edition (2008).

Comment: One more simple observation showing that the two variable assumption is, indeed, necessary in the claim from Fulton's book: if we take let's say our example $g=x^2+y^2, f=x$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and look at the polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$, then $V(g)=\{(0,0,c)\ |\ c\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is infinite, but we still have $V(g)\subseteq V(f)$ and $g$ does not divide $f$.

Comment: Indeed, nicely observed! The proof reduces to the one-variable case, and therefore does not generalise.